# Is there a SFDC tool to quickly load - and reload - test data?

Tags: data-loader, migration-tool, tools

Is there already a SFDC tool that will take a set of test data - similar to what is part of every developer org - and load it into a new developer sandbox?

Is there a tool to wipe out an entire org's data, in order to get ready to reload the test data?

I am aware of Data Loader and similar tools for loading data - I am tired of using those and am looking for something more efficient.

I am assuming that I would have to follow some sort of CSV or JSON formatting - but before I build my own tools here, I want to see if something similar already exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're look to copy data into a Sandbox from Production (or another Sandbox) and then do something stuff and then delete the data, then reload etc, you could use the SFXOrgData app (http://www.sfApex.com) which let you copy data and also delete data from your target org.

Answer (score 8):

There is [Test.loadData(sObjectToken, resourceName)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_loadData) which can be used to load a number of testing records from a CSV file stored as a static resource.

This is great if the intention of the data is for running automated test cases. Not so useful if you want to setup an org for an actual user.

Comment: Unsurprisingly after many years, the documentation has changed. Here's the current link to the loadData() method https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm?search_text=loaddata

Comment: @JulianHarty Thanks, I've updated the link the an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To wipe out a sandbox, simply refresh from Production and activate the refreshed sandbox.

If it is not a full copy sandbox, the data will be wiped clean.

DreamFactory do a tool called [Monarch](http://www.dreamfactory.com/solutions/monarch), which I have seen widely used for moving data between sandboxes for setting up seed test data.

Also, although it isn't really meant for this, I've read about Salesforce 2 Salesforce being used for this purpose, although I haven't tried it out myself.

Dataloader can be quite handy if you have a set of CSV files and external id fields on each object to marry up the relational data on load. You could save the mappings and make this process repeatable by setting up Dataloader to run [command line](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line).